# UIDatePicker vs. UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I'm handling **UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification** in my app and all the other screens in the app are gracefully refreshed when midnight comes. The one I have trouble with is with **UIDatePicker**. **UIPickerView** has **refreshAllComponents** method which I use in another screen to make an update on midnight change. I would like to have the same for **UIDatePicker**, but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to refresh it, and *Today* remains *Today*, although it is already *Yesterday*. Any way out?

Comment: Experiencing this same issue - did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Why not replace the UIDatePicker with new instance?

```
UIDatePicker *oldPicker = self.myDatePicker;
UIDatePicker *newPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:oldPicker.frame];
[newPicker setDate:oldPicker.date animated:NO];
[[oldPicker superview] addSubview:newPicker];
[oldPicker removeFromSuperview];
self.myDatePicker = newPicker;
[newPicker release];
```

The above code will swap oldPicker for newPicker, copying settings so no one will notice the change. If you have other references to the picker view, you'll need to update them, too.

Comment: One could use it as a workaround. However I'm not sure it will look great visually. Will need to try... Thanks for your thoughts anyway.

Comment: The swap will be instantaneous, so visually the user shouldn't notice. Or you could enable animations so that the user sees the change as a crossfade. Either way, it shouldn't be jarring.

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the UIDatePicker using its method

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Simply pass as the date argument [NSDate date] and YES as the animated argument.
This should work since after midnight [NSDate date] must produce the correct current date.

Comment: Same shit. Yes, it moves to the next date, but what was Today remains Today, while it is already yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old topic, but as I found it with google, so will other people.
What worked for me :

```
[datePicker becomeFirstResponder];
[datePicker reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: If this is a proper answer, sorry I'm not `ticking` it, since I just have no time to proove it.